# desplazar un objeto div cuando se crea una alerta de bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema creado alertas de formularios con `bootstrap`. El caso que se debe de lanzar una alerta cuando el usuario no mete los datos según unos parámetros establecidos. Yo lo tengo de la siguiente manera.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="use" >
    A simple danger alert—check it out!
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" 
   placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</form>
```

Este es el bloque `html`, el caso es que consigo lanzar la alerta usando `jquery` y el `display:none` o `display:inline` usando el selector del `ID`. Pero cuando se muestra se pone encima del siguiente campo.

Alguien sabe como puedo mostrarlo sin que se ponga encima?

Comment: Prueba  poniendo el div del alert dentro del div "form-group"

Comment: buenas ahora en vez de quedarse encima del siguiente campo se queda encima del propio div.